# Prove $A=\{g\in G: |g^G|< \infty \}$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

> Let $G$ be a group acting on itself.
>
> Prove $A=\{g\in G: |g^G|< \infty \}$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G$

I've found the following question: [Does the subgroup $\{g\in G\,|\,o(\operatorname{Cl}(g))<\infty\}$ of $G$ have a name?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108346/does-the-subgroup-g-in-g-o-operatornameclg-infty-of-g-have-a) In that question the group action is specified as conjugation, but the exercise in the text I'm reading does not specify this.

This leads me to ask whether this would be valid in a more general setting as well, when the group action is not specified.

#### Idea

I have an idea, but I think it flawed. Is it? And is this theorem true in the **general** case?

1. Notice how $A \not = \varnothing$, since $1\in A$
2. Choose $g,h \in A$, does $gh^{-1}\in A$?

   Consider the function $\psi: g^G\to (gh^{-1})^G; g^a \mapsto (gh^{-1})^a$ which maps the orbit $g^G$ to the orbit $(gh^{-1})^G$.
   This function is surjective, which implies $\infty > |g^G|\geqslant |(gh^{-1})^G|$. Which would imply $gh^{-1} \in A$.

   **Flaw 1: I think the function $\psi$ is not well defined (?)**
3. Characteristic subgroup?

   Choose a $\theta \in \mathrm{Aut}(G)$, now is $A^\theta = A$?

   Choose a $g\in A$, I have to prove $g\in A^\theta = \{g\in G: |g^G|<\infty\}^\theta = \{g^\theta\in G: |g^G|< \infty\}$

   Notice how $g=h^\theta$ for a unique $h\in G$, namely $h=g^{\theta^{-1}}$, does now $|h^G|< \infty$?

   Consider $\psi: g^G\to h^G; g^a\mapsto (g^{\theta^{-1}})^a$ which is once again surjective. Then $|h^G|\leqslant |g^G|< \infty$.

   **Once again I think the function $\psi$ is not well defined (?)**

Comment: If $G$ acts on itself by translation, then the orbit of every $g \in G$ is all of $G$, so $A = \emptyset$ or $A = G$ depending on whether $G$ is infinite or not.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I think $G$ is supposed to act on himself as a group, i.e. the action is supposed to be given by a group homomorphism $G\to Aut(G)$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. You have a proof of the claim for an arbitrary $G \to Aut(G)$? The case of acting by conjugation is easy; I don't know about that level of generality.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I mean, the question should've said "Let $G$ be a group acting on itself by automorphisms" in that case. Just like it should've said "Let $G$ be a group acting on itself by conjugation" if that was the intended meaning.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein To be honest, I hadn't read the question carefully enough and thought it was an exercise from some book or other. I hadn't realized it was just OP asking if something more general is true. So you raise a good point, OP should clarify a bit what is meant precisely.

Comment: @ArnaudD. OP does claim to be quoting the question from a text.

Comment: It is an exercise from some course notes, and the specification of the group action is indeed missing. However it is found in a section regarding "*a group acting on itself by conjugation*" which makes sense. I wondered though if the general statement would still be true if it would be "*a group action on itself by automorphism*". Giving it further thought I'm rather convinced that the flaws I remarked are indeed flaws...